# Invalid customer key error when sending an email with with the "Fuel SDK for C#"

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, c#

I'm trying to send an email with the [Fuel SDK for C#](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp), but am running into issues with an invalid customer key error. I've double checked my customer key is correct, perhaps there is something else I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's my attempt at coding this

```
ETTriggeredSendDefinition eTTriggeredSendDefinition = new ETTriggeredSendDefinition();
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.AuthStub = client;
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Name = "DevTest";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.CustomerKey = "ABC";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.FromAddress = "test@example.com";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.EmailSubject = "Test Email";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Email = new Email();
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Email.HTMLBody = "%3Cb%3ESome%20HTML%20Goes%20here%3C%2Fb%3E";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Email.EmailType = "HTML";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers = new ETSubscriber[1];
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers[0] = new ETSubscriber();
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers[0].EmailAddress = "test@example.com";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers[0].Owner = new Owner();
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers[0].Owner.FromAddress = "test@example.com";
eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Subscribers[0].Owner.FromName = "test@example.com";
SendReturn sendReturn = eTTriggeredSendDefinition.Send()
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! We're going to need a little more information in order to assist you. Please take a moment to read about [ask], then [edit] your post to include more information. In particular, which SDK are you using? Which API are you trying to use? The more information you give us, the better we can assist you.

Comment: @sfdcfox i have edited my question.

Comment: @siddharth is this related to salesforce? not familiar with fuel, so not clear if that's related to salesforce or not ...

Comment: @RalphCallaway they mean [FuelSDK-CSharp](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp). It's Marketing Cloud stuff.

Comment: @siddharth can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @siddharth you might also consider posting an issue to the [github repo for FuelSDC C#](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp)

Answer (score 1):

I was just researching this -- the "invalid customer key" means you passed an external key that is not recognized by the system.

Your example of `eTTriggeredSendDefinition.CustomerKey = "ABC";`  looks like the issue to me, but I'm not an API expert.  Instead, find the customer key in the properties of your email or your Triggered Send.

For example, one of my keys is for email is `267a0971-0ba7-4xxx-xxxx-df6209dxxxxx` (edited for privacy) and one for a triggered send is `19992` (again, edited for privacy).

These can be found in the UI

Change the customer key and give it another try.